# Problema con fecha en Carbon

Tags: php, laravel, date

Obtengo una fecha `date` de la base de datos y al mostrarla, el día y el mes, son correctos, pero el año no.

Así obtengo la fecha de la base de datos:

```
$fecha_ingreso = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($user->fecha_ingreso); //2016-05-05
```

Y esto es lo que me imprime por pantalla:

> object(Carbon\Carbon)#260 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2155-05-05 00:00:00.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(3) "UTC" }

¿Qué puede causar este error?

Si lo hago con la fecha actual me lo muestra correctamente, pero con la fecha de la  base de datos no.

Comment: ¿cómo pasas la fecha de hoy? teniendo en cuenta que dices que esa sí funciona.

Comment: Hola! La fecha actual me la muestra correctamente, pero la que traigo de la base de datos no, que debo usar para sacar la diferencia entre las dos fechas.
La fecha actual la obtengo asi:
$hoy = \Carbon\Carbon::now(); //today
Gracias...

Comment: La verdad es que para probar hice exactamente lo mismo que estás haciendo y me funcionó perfectamente, lo probé en PHP7, no puedo reproducir tu problema, lo cual nos deja dos posibilidades: 1. La variable que pasas tiene algún formato particular o 2. hay un problema con tu servidor y/o la versión de PHP.

Comment: Hago un var_dump() de $user->fecha_ingreso y me dice string...

Comment: El valor de la fecha en la base de datos es `2016-05-05` ?, si no lo es por favor comenta cual es el valor de la fecha en la base de datos.

Comment: Si, 2016-05-05 es la fecha en la base de datos.

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Puedes utilizar createFromFormat para decirle a Carbon qué formato utilizar

```
$fecha_ingreso = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $user->fecha_ingreso)
```